# expand a GridPane to max width and height

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

is it possible to expand a grid pane to max width and height?

i have the following:

```
<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
         stylesheets="view/Style.css">
    <children>
        <GridPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
                  AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="128.0"
                  AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0"
                  hgap="10" vgap="10">
            <!--anything-->
        </GridPane>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

and i'd like to expand the grid pane to the limits determined by the anchor pane (so whole screen except the lower part)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try set maxHeight and maxWidth properties of GridPane.

```
maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity"
```

And childrens of GridPane should contain

```
GridPane.hgrow="always" GridPane.vgrow="always"
```

Comment: Thank you, but what's the point of the maxHeight and maxWidth? That part didn't make any difference in my application.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using JavaFX directly without fxml. The code is:

```
GridPane.setHgrow(childElementOfGridPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
GridPane.setVgrow(childElementOfGridPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
```